# How to preview asciidoc in vscode with a file with a yaml extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, yaml, preview, asciidoc, mixed

I have a file which contains YAML at the top and asciidoc at the bottom. The yaml is surrounded by two lines of ---. The file extension is yaml which is required by the application where it's used.

The only way i know to get a preview out of vscode is to manually rename the file every time i need one and rename it back afterwards.

Is there a way to open the asciidoc preview in vscode while ignoring its extension, e.g. giving a hint, add a configuration or something similar?
[The docs](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=asciidoctor.asciidoctor-vscode) only describe that

> The extension activates automatically when opening an AsciiDoc file
> (.adoc, .ad, .asc, .asciidoc).

Here's a example file:

```
---
# yaml here
---
asciidoc here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is surprisingly simple:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_changing-the-language-for-the-selected-file

> In VS Code, we default the language support for a file based on its
> filename extension. However, at times you may want to change language
> modes, to do this click on the language indicator - which is located
> on the right hand of the Status Bar. This will bring up the Select
> Language Mode dropdown where you can select another language for the
> current file.
>
> Tip: You can get the same dropdown by running the Change Language Mode command `(Ctrl+K M)`.

Answer (score 1):

Not to mess with language switching I extract embedded code into separate file and then include it into adoc like this:

```
.CLE Product organization
[plantuml]
----
include::cle-product.puml[]
----
```

This allows having proper preview and syntax highlighting.